# Confusion regarding *.desktop files: okular.desktop appears multiple times in Nautilus // okular.desktop vs. okularApplication____.desktop

Tags: command-line, nautilus, .desktop

Source of confusion [regarding *.desktop files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Entries), see screenshot below, multiple files of *almost* exact same size and exact same (modification) date, same-but-different ?

[image: nautilus]

Here's a screenshot of the properties, (seems to be) same for all:

[image: nautilus_properties]

`View > Visible columns...` also leads to no-where promising...

But, lo and behold, in `terminal` the `ls` command reveals some arcane differences:

[image: command line - ls]

Now I was actually only interested in locating and identifying the one-and-only (?) `okular.desktop` file, *not* all the other `okularApplication_{xxxxxx}.desktop` files.

How? And what's the story of the other files?

---

**EDIT**

Copied desktop files to non-system folder: Nautilus reveals more info... (which doesn't help from *within* `/usr/share/applications/`)

[image: copied desktop files to non-system folder]

Answer (score 1):

`.desktop` files are simple text files. All you need to do is have a look at the contents to see the differences between them.

As far as I can tell, these are just different `.desktop` files for different file formats that open with `okular`.

I'm not sure what you're actually asking. If you're asking how you can find the "Real" `okular` desktop file, it's the one that's actually *called* `okular.desktop`:

```
ls /usr/share/applications/kde4/okular.desktop
```

To see the differences, you can run `diff`. For example:

```
 diff okular.desktop okularApplication_dvi.desktop
```

That will show you that the differences are basically in the mimetypes and KDE categories associated with each `.desktop` file. These are just internal tricks used by the desktop environment (KDE for example) to correctly classify programs in its menus and file associations. For example, the plain `okular.desktop` is categorized as

```
$ grep Categories okular.desktop
Categories=Qt;KDE;Graphics;Office;Viewer;
```

While the `okularApplication_dvi.desktop` (which is `okular` acting as  `.dvi` viewer) is:

```
$ grep Categories okularApplication_dvi.desktop
Categories=Qt;KDE;Graphics;Viewer;
```

Note that it is not categorized as `Office` since this is okular in its manifestation as a dvi viewer.

Basically, these are all internal details that you can safely ignore. Whenever you want to find the `.desktop` file for a program, just look for `ProgramName.desktop` and ignore the rest.

Comment: Right, now remember opening and editing `*.desktop` files with gedit in the past... However, from the first screenshot: how do I pick the right one / how can I hold them apart in Nautilus (non-command line)? But basically I'm sorted: what I was trying to do is anyway command line based.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty no idea, I never use a file browser for this kind of thing and they seem to have decided to mimic Windows and hide the scary real names from the stupid users. No idea why. Presumably, there will be an option somewhere in nautilus that tells it to show the actual _file_ name instead of this prettified and useless crap.